# finding the palindrome string using recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
bool palindrome(char input[], int siz, int start){
    // siz = size of the array ,start =starting point of the array ie 0
    if(input[start] == '\0') {
        return true;
    } else if(input[start] == input[siz - start - 1]) {
        return true;
        palindrome(input, siz, start + 1);
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

I am trying to find the palindrome string using this recursive function but the code outputs the term `alia` as palindrome as if it is checking only the first and the last alphabets of the strings.
The base case i took is when there is null element found on the starting of the array then it returns true .
else if the first and the last elements are equal then it returns true and recursively calls itself by `palindrome(input,siz,start+1)` else it returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are exiting the function before executing it again.
Right now you have

```
else if(input[start]==input[siz-start-1])
        {
            return true;
            palindrome(input,siz,start+1);
        }
```

Instead, try

```
else if(input[start]==input[siz-start-1])
        {
            palindrome(input,siz,start+1);
        }
```

Then at the end of the function, add

```
return true;
```

EDIT:

I tested it out and it worked fine for me, here's the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
bool palindrome(char input[],int siz,int start){
    //siz =size of the array ,start =starting point of the array ie 0
    if(input[start]=='\0')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(input[start]==input[siz-start-1])
    {
        palindrome(input,siz,start+1);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    char racecar[] = "racecar";
    if (palindrome(racecar, 7, 0))
    {
        std::cout << "It's a palindrome!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "It's not a palindrome." << std::endl;
    }
    char abba[] = "abba";
    if (palindrome(abba, 4, 0))
    {
        std::cout << "It's a palindrome!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "It's not a palindrome." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it again since the edit I added of the full code?

Answer (score 0):

This sould work:

```
#include <iostream>

bool isPalindromeRecursive(char* string, int begin, int end)
{
    if (begin == strlen(string) / 2) // There is no point in comparing chars past half of the string lenght
    {
        return true;
    }
    // Is the first char the same as the last char? <-- we call recursion based on that statement
    return tolower(string[begin]) == tolower(string[end]) && isPalindromeRecursive(string, ++begin, --end);
}
bool isPalindrome(char* string)
{
    return isPalindromeRecursive(string, 0, strlen(string)-1); // Let's  ignore the null char (strlen(string)-1)
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << isPalindrome("hooh") << std::endl;
}
```